# Android: how can I disable play protect through device policy manager as device owner?

Tags: android, android-package-managers, device-owner

When I try to download and install a 3rd party app using the PackageInstaller service from my device owner/provisioning app Google Play shows a prompt before the app is installed. I can accept or decline and it doesnt affect the installation, but does pause the installation until an answer is given, so I'd like to hide it.

Comment: are you found solution ?

Comment: sorry for the bump on old post, did you find a solution

Answer (score 0):

You can just disable google play before updating and then enable it back

```
val dpm = application.getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE) as DevicePolicyManager
val componentName = ComponentName(application, AdminReceiver::class.java)
if (!dpm.isAdminActive(componentName)) return

dpm.setApplicationHidden(componentName, "com.android.vending", disabled)
```